# Multiple whereIn clauses don't return expected results

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I need to filter products based on search terms, so I have this in my controller:

```php
$activeFilters = Array(
    "Display dimensions" => Array("5' inches","5.5' inches"),
    "Color" => Array("Grey","Black")
);

$product = Product->whereHas("attributes", function($query) use ($activeFilters){
    foreach($activeFilters as $group){
        $query = $query->whereIn("product_features.text", $group);
    }
})->get();
```

Now if I set inside active filters array only one group (ex. Display dimensions) with its values, the query returns expected results. When I append a second group, as in the code, the result is empty, even if a product matching those filters exists inside products table.

Comment: you are doing an AND where. I guess you need a OR.

Comment: I've tried to add 'or'  in whereIn clause but i get all products as result, so unfortunately it's not the way.

Comment: you might be able to use `orWhereIn` rather than `whereIn`

Answer (score 0):

Try parameter grouping with orWhereIn for logical OR

```php
$product = Product::whereHas("attributes", function($query) use ($activeFilters){
  $query->where(function($query) use ($activeFilters) {
    foreach($activeFilters as $group){
        $query->orWhereIn("product_features.text", $group);
    }
  });
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. With **orWhere** (as suggested in your answers) I'm obtaining a result that contains all products with:

- Display dimensions: 5' inches and 5.5' inches
- Color: Grey, Black

To obtain expected result I've used multiple whereHas as in the code below:

```
$activeFilters = Array(
    "Display dimensions" => Array("5' inches","5.5' inches"),
    "Color" => Array("Grey","Black")
);

$firstFilter = array_shift($activeFilters);

$product = Product::whereHas("attributes", function($query) use ($firstFilter){
    return $query->whereIn("product_features.text", $firstFilter);
}

foreach($activeFilters as $group){
    $product = $product->whereHas("attributes", function($query) use ($group){
        return $query->whereIn("product_features.text", $group);
    }
})

$product = $product->get();
```

In this way i'm obtaining products that have display 5' inches or 5.5' inches AND are grey or black

Comment: Every time you call `whereHas` you add a subquery. This is not scalable.